# Python rearrange json

Tags: json

I have following script to generate json data:

```
    with open(res_file, 'w') as f:
        for i, box in enumerate(boxes):
            poly = np.array(box).astype(np.int32).reshape((-1))
            strResult = ','.join([str(p) for p in poly]) + '\n'
            #f.write(str(i)+' ['+strResult)
            json.dump(strResult, f)
```

The output I get from this script is as follows:

> "429,44,436,44,436,56,429,56\n""345,41,431,44,430,69,344,66\n""453,42,554,42,554,68,453,68\n""654,45,710,45,710,76,654,76\n""436,48,449,48,449,66,436,66\n""153,58,287,61,286,97,152,93\n""345,70,438,70,438,94,345,94\n""442,69,477,69,477,94,442,94\n""481,69,602,69,602,94,481,94\n""638,76,724,76,724,94,638,94\n""293,117,313,117,313,132,293,132\n""316,117,361,117,361,132,316,132\n""362,117,396,117,396,132,362,132\n""330,140,481,142,481,165,330,162\n""330,168,537,168,537,189,330,189\n""466,193,544,193,544,213,466,213\n""330,194,370,194,370,214,330,214\n"

However I want to rearrage this output in the following json format:

```
{
"Message":"success",
"Status":1,
"Result" :
"0" :
"0":[1,1],
"1":[1,1],
"2":[1,1],
"3":[1,1]
},
"1" :
"0":[1,1],
"1":[1,1],
"2":[1,1],
"3":[1,1]
}
}
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare your output as a dictionary (as it seems that you are requesting as the desired output) before you dump it as a JSON. Here is one way to do it (please observe that I'm working with lists and you should adapt it to your numpy array model):

```
    result = {}
    result["Message"] ="success"
    result["Status"] = 1
    result_boxes = {}
    for i, box in enumerate(boxes):
        # poly = np.array(box).astype(np.int32).reshape((-1))
        poly = box
        result_lines = {}
        for y in range(4):
            result_lines[str(y)]=[poly[(y*2)],poly[(y*2)+1]]
        result_boxes[str(i)] = result_lines
    result["Result"] = result_boxes
    json.dump(result, f)
```

Also remember that dictionaries in Python will not keep the same order. This is the output I got:

```
{ 
    "Status":1,
    "Message":"success",
    "Result":{ 
        "1":{ 
            "1":[431,44],
            "0":[345,41],
            "3":[344,66],
            "2":[430,69]
        },
        "0":{ 
            "1":[436,44],
            "0":[429,44],
            "3":[429,56],
            "2":[436,56]
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!